# javascript regex to extract the first character after the last specified character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the first character after the last underscore in a string with an unknown number of '_' in the string but in my case there will always be one, because I added it in another step of the process.

What I tried is this. I also tried the regex by itself to extract from the name, but my result was empty.

```
var s = "XXXX-XXXX_XX_DigitalF.pdf"

var string = match(/[^_]*$/)[1]

string.charAt(0)
```

So the final desired result is 'D'. If the RegEx can only get me what is behind the last '_' that is fine because I know I can use the charAt like currently shown. However, if the regex can do the whole thing, even better.

Comment: With `[0]` it works. That's because there is only one match for the regexp.

Comment: I wondered about that... Yeah, that worked thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know there will always be at least one underscore you can do this:

```
var s = "XXXX-XXXX_XX_DigitalF.pdf"

var firstCharAfterUnderscore = s.charAt(s.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);

// OR, with regex

var firstCharAfterUnderscore = s.match(/_([^_])[^_]*$/)[1]
```

With the regex, you can extract just the one letter by using parentheses to capture that part of the match. But I think the `.lastIndexOf()` version is easier to read.

Either way if there's a possibility of no underscores in the input you'd need to add some additional logic.

Comment: I'm with you, reading the regex is painful for me. Thanks so much for the speedy answer.